# Returning tab content in two seperate places using Twitter Bootstrap's data-toggle="tab"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm activating bootstrap.js tabs by specifying data-toggle="tab" in my navbar:

```
<li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Look Inside</a></li>
```

Then, returning the content of those tabs with:

```
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">Content
</div>
</div>
```

I'm wondering how I can possibly return the same content to two separate places on the page, each in seperate div's. As of now, I add:

... for a second time after the first div had been closed (I have to close it because I have a horizontal navbar in between the top content and the bottom content) and it doesn't return content.

Is there any way I can call "tab-content" something else and still have it maintain twitter bootstrap functionality.

TY

Comment: Are you trying to get two `div`s to show at once?

Comment: Hi Ron, yes I am. One above the navbar, and one below it.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this.  One is pure CSS, taking advantage of the fact that the bootstrap dropdown will open any menu.  For instance:

myvew.html.haml

```
%ul.nav.nav-pills
  %li.dropdown
    %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown"}
      Foo
      %b.caret
    %ul.dropdown-menu{style: "position: relative; top: -10px;"}
      %li Bar1
    %ul.dropdown-menu
      %li Bar2
```

What this will do is that when the "Foo" link is clicked, both "Bar1" and "Bar2" are shown.

---

However, I tend to prefer this approach:  register an event listener onto the "Foo" link, and then the event listener toggles `.show()` or `.hide()` for the target `div`s.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myclickdiv').click(function() {
    $('.mydivs').collapse("show");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ron...I'm still a bit confused...here's a little better description of what I'm trying to do...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859415/how-to-return-same-tab-content-to-two-separate-divs

Comment: (I'm stilla nube at all of this :)