# How to return content to two separate tabbable ID's upon one tab click using Twitter Bootstrap's Tabbable Tabs in a Rails 3.2 App

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Using Twitter Bootstrap's bootstrap-tab.js, I have:

```
<ul class="tabnavcenter" id="myTab">
   <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">about</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">education</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">experience</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">verified skills</a></li>
   <li><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab"> video</a></li>
 </ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Content 1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

How can I get it so if I put:

```
 <div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Content 2</div>
 </div>
```

... two places in the profile (once above and once below a navbar) and with different content in each, it would work? As of now, the content appears, but once its clicked, it disappears. Can there be two "active" li's at the same time?

Edit:

Since I'm using this in a Rails 3.2 App, I currently have the following in bootstrap-tab.js:

```
 $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');
})


 $('#myTab a[href="#home"]').tab('show');
 $('#myTab a[href="#tab2"]').tab('show');
 $('#myTab a[href="#tab3"]').tab('show');
 $('#myTab a[href="#tab4"]').tab('show');
 $('#myTab a[href="#tab5"]').tab('show');
 $('#myTab a[href="#home2"]').tab('show');
 $('#myTab a[href="#tab22"]').tab('show');
```

and after putting the following in user_body.html.erb:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
       $('#myTab >li>a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
        //
        $(this.getAttribute('href') + '2').html($(this).html());
       });
   });
```

... I get the second content in the div after refreshing the page, no change when I click on the second tab, and then a change back to the name of the first 'a' when I click back on the first one.

It's a mess.

Comment: Are you saying you want one set of tabs to control two (separate) sets of panes?

Comment: Isn't this an exact duplicate of your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127973/returning-tab-content-id-to-two-divs-using-tabbable-tabs ?

Comment: @GirlCanCode2 Accept an answer so i can award answer which worked for you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is one solution without extra javascript, and compatible with the plugin API.

The principle is to use 2 `.tab-content` and take advantage of the `data-target` selector attribute.

### HTML

The first `.tab-content` contains your *normal* `.tab-pane`

```html
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane home-tab">class home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane profile-tab">profile</div>
    <div class="tab-pane messages-tab">messages</div>
    <div class="tab-pane settings-tab">settings</div>
</div>
```

and the second `.tab-content` contains the extra `.tab-pane`s that are optionnal - **plus an empty one** (`#notab_else` here)

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home_else">home_else</div>
    <div class="tab-pane home-tab">class home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane profile-tab messages-tab settings-tab" id="notab_else"></div>
</div>
```

Then you have your tabs with one extra attribute, `data-target` :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-target="#home, #home_else">Home</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#home" data-target=".home-tab">Class Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile" data-target=".profile-tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages" data-target=".messages-tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings" data-target=".settings-tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
```

This attribute `data-target` defines the `.tab-pane`(s) associated with it. The magic is that you can use `#id`s or `.class`es or any valid jQuery selector.

### JavaScript

All you need to activate everything is the default code :

```js
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

And you can also use your own actions to trigger the tabs as defined by the API.

You **do not need** that if you keep the default behavior for tabs.

```
$('#myTab a:first').tab('show');
```

### EXTRA

- You can be free of any javascript if you set `data-toggle="tab"` to the `a` elements
- There is a fade effect available if you add the `fade` class to the `.tab-pane` (and `fade in` for the `.active` one)

### DEMOS

Here is the [demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/MSD2J/1/) and the [demo with extra (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/MSD2J/3/)

Comment: Sherbrow, I can't tell you how helpful this was for me. Thank you so much for such a well thought out and well articulated answer. (and apologies for the delayed reply response, I thought my previous comment had gone through a while back :P).

Comment: @GirlCanCode2 I'm glad. If you can, don't hesitate to post a link to your implementation of this, for a real world example.

Answer (score 2):

you can only access one id at a time, this is why it is called an id.

Get the content from the first one and apply it to the second one.

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).tab('show');

   $(this.href +'2').html($(this.href).html()

})


<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Content 1</div>

</div>


 <div class="tab-content2">
   <div class="tab-pane active" id="home2">Content 2</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi Vinyl, Am I to put "#home" instead of "#myTab a"? It's not currently working...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working solution for your problem (updated):

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Tab-1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Tab-2</div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content" id="tab-content2">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home2">Home Content 2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile2">Profile Tab-2</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tab-content2 div").each(function(i, e){ 
        if(!$(e).hasClass('active')) $(e).hide();
    });
    $('#myTab>li>a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
        $("#tab-content2 div").each(function(i, e) {
            $(e).hide();
        });
        $(this.getAttribute('href') + "2").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, this is working except it displays both "Home Content 2" and "Profile Tab-2" by default, and doesn't change to each individual one until I click on it. Is there a way I could integrate "$('#myTab a:first').tab('show');" into it? Thank YOU!

Comment: Yeah, when I get home later I'll update my response to hide those items by default

Comment: I updated my response to only show the "active" divs on load.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myTab >li>a').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab('show');
            //
            $('#extendedView').html($(this).html());
        });
    });
</script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Tab-1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Tab-2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Tab-3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Tab-4</div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content2">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="extendedView">Content 2</div>
```

### OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myTab >li>a').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab('show');
            //
            $(this.getAttribute('href') + '2').html($(this).html());
        });
    });
</script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
    <li><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">Tab-1</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">Tab-2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">Tab-3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">Tab-4</div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content2">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home2"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile2"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages2"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="settings2"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Still not working. The first one you just suggested returned the name of each tab in the content below though